# Crossing from Sarnia to Port Huron, MI in a car without a passport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, canada, canadian-citizens

Can we drive across the blue water bridge from Canada to the US and back without a passport?

We have proof of Canadian citizenship but our passports just expired.

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1192/~/canadian--citizens/residents/landed-immigrants-entering-the-u.s.

Comment: Are you asking if  you can drive over the bridge, then  pull a U-turn on the U.S. side of the bridge and retreat to Canada before engaging the U.S. officials? It looks like there is access from the left lane, but not sure you want to do that- it might raise questions,  even if it isn't blocked somehow.

Answer (score 11):

If you're a Canadian citizen coming to visit the US by land, you can present [any of the following documents](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1192/~/canadian--citizens/residents/landed-immigrants-entering-the-u.s.):

- A valid passport;
- A valid [NEXUS card](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/menu-eng.html);
- A valid [enhanced driver license](http://www.ontario.ca/driving-and-roads/enhanced-drivers-licence).

(You can also use a SENTRI or FAST/EXPRES card, but unless you travel to Mexico a lot or are a commercial truck driver you aren't likely to have one of these.)

If you haven't got any of those documents, you may wish to postpone your trip or [apply for expedited passport renewal](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/passport/times.asp).